# PL\SQL with ODP, Reading with DataReader out of RefCursor

Tags: c#, plsql, odp.net

I have writed a PL\SQL function than reuturn a REF CURSOR

```
OPEN REFCURSOR FOR
SELECT bla bla bla..
```

And I left it open so I could read from it in the ODP program.

In the C# side, I got the result out of the command as IDataReader.

The problem is that the program has waited for all the data to generate first, and just then I could start reading from the DataReader.
I am getting big data from this Function and the fact that I have to wait for the first result to come is bugging me.

If I take out this select query out of a function and put it on a DataReader everything is working fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about the perf of your stored proc or the perf tuning optimizations for ado.net? At the moment, it sounds like you have a slow query. If it takes 10 seconds before Oracle starts sending packets, then the DataReader will block for 10 seconds before it can read the first row.

Comment: If I didn't make it clear. I I put the query on regular command and then read from it With DataReader, the first result come immediate, But with sored proc it make it load all the results first, and just then relase the first result to the DataReader. It's not good of couse, so I want a solution to put a query in stored proc and get the first result immediatly

Comment: Show some code-- in particular enough to see if the PLSQL returns more than one result set, and just enough of the ADO.NET code to see what the general strategy is.

Comment: I'am not doing anything special in the code.. Just ExecuteReader the command and Read() from the result which it IDataReader.. If I debug it I can see that it is stuck on the Read() line in about 30 seconds which I guess is because the stored procedure force the query to load all the rows first and just than send it to the DataReader.

Comment: Try playing around with OracleDataReader.Fetchsize values to see if you can get better performance.